# Emulate "Sphere" image texture in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, texture-coordinates

I would like to use an image to adjust geometry of a sphere. I am using an icosphere to avoid the loss of resolution near the equator.

In the shader node this is accomplished with this setup.

[image]

In geometry nodes you can achieve "generated" but there is no option to change the image texture to Sphere.

[image]

Thus the geometry is messed up

[image]

There must be some kind of transformation to get the image into Sphere mode right? How would I go about that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Sphere Projection* uses the [Spherical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system):

- *radial distance* $r$ (or $ρ$) is not used, because it’s a projection,
- *azimuth* $\varphi$ (also known as a [polar coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system)) is translated to $x$ in the texture,
- *inclination* (*elevation*) $θ$ is translated to $y$ in the texture.

[image]

There are some [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) problems visible on the azimuth seam and from far away in the *Difference* blending, and even when zooming some differences can still be spotted – maybe the algorithm could be improved by e.g. changing the orders of calculations, so the float errors are reduced?

[image]

In geometry nodes you don’t have the *Generated* coordinate system, but you don’t need it, and in fact, using the *Object* coordinate system is simpler, because you can remove the first *Vector Math*, which makes sure the center of sphere is in the origin:

[image]

*Math: Arctan2* node outputs a value in range $-90°..+90°$, but expressed in radians (in memory in Blender angles are always represented as radians, though by default displayed as degrees, with the degree ° symbol) $=-{π\over 2} .. +{π \over 2}$ so from $-1.57…$ to $+1.57…$. The UV space however is normalized in $0..1$ range, so this node is a more performant way of a Map Range like so:

[image]

Explaining using Python: (keep in mind `_` means the result of last operation, previously displayed)

```py
>>> radians(90)  # what is the range -90deg .. +90deg expressed in radians?
1.5707963267948966  # range from -1.57... to +1.57...

>>> 0.5 / _  # a * b = 0.5, therefore b = 0.5 / a (div both sides by a)
0.3183098861837907

>>> radians(90) * _  # obtained number, times the range gives -0.5..+0.5
0.5

>>> # and -0.5 .. +0.5 , can be normalized to 0..1 by adding 0.5
```

To further clarify, in the 2nd operation's comment, I mean that we have a range $-a .. +a$, and we want to multiply it by some number $b$, so that the range is $-0.5 .. +0.5$ (when normalizing a symmetric range, always first convert it to 0.5 on either side, and then add 0.5). To find this number $b$, just transform the formula describing the problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very nice. Thanks my guy.

Comment: I keep coming back to this because it's helped me so many times. But I was wondering. What Multiply + Add node do with the 0.318 and 0.5 values respectively?

Comment: @TheJeran If you look around the node, you will see a hint: https://i.imgur.com/5OA56bw.png see the update.